# Use R to merge a large collection of dissimilar data.frames into a list of lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a collection of five R dataframes with varying columns. Each `data.frame` includes a unique identifier ID. For some of the dataframes, there is a one-to-one relationship between the ID and the remaining columns (that is, for each ID, there is one row of data in the `data.frame`). For other dataframes, there is a one-to-many relationship between the ID and the remaining columns (one ID, with many rows of data in the `data.frame` associated with that one ID). The data come from an SQL database, so the dataframes are structured from queries made against that database. **It is also important to point out that not all IDs appear in every `data.frame`. So, between the five dataframes, there isn't a common set of IDs.** When you get to the code below, that is the reason for the sub-setting that I do.

I want to recombine the five dataframes I have into a list of lists, where each member of the list of lists is a 5-part list containing all the data of each ID. Each part of each member of the list is a `data.frame` with only the data from that ID.

So far, I am using a simple `for` loop with subsetting by ID inside the loop to do this in R. It works reliably, but when my ID count gets into the 10's of thousands, it can take 30+ minutes, maybe hours, to restructure the data using the `for` loop approach. I know that `for` loops are generally frowned upon in R, but I have not figured out a different way to do this quickly and efficiently, despite many hours searching the internet for how this might work. I have an `lapply` version of the `for` loop that looks similar, but it didn't seem to help much.

I do not know if the speed issue is because of the `for` loop use, or if all the sub-setting is the reason for the slowdown. If it would help of normalize the dataframes to a common set of IDs, then I can certainly do that. Although, I am unsure at the moment how to do that.

Here is my R-code of the `for` loop so you can see what I am doing now. Note that I pre-allocate my container for the list of lists, which helps speed things up within the context of this approach.

```
  numIDs <- nrows(df1)
  final.list <- vector(mode="list",length=numIDs)
  for (i in 1:numIDs) {
    wd <- df1[i,]
    pd <- df2[df2$id==wd$id,]
    fd <- df3[df3$id==wd$id,]
    dd <- df4[df4$id==wd$id,]
    ed <- df5[df5$id==wd$id,]
    final.list[[i]] <- list(rdf1=wd,rdf2=pd,rdf3=fd,rdf4=dd,rdf5=ed)
  }
```

Here is some example data that shows what I am trying to do.

```
df1<-data.frame("id"=c("r1","r2","r3"),"c1"=c(1,2,3),"c2"=c("a","b","c"),stringsAsFactors=F)
df2<-data.frame("id"=c("r1","r3"),"d1"=c(1000,3000),"d2"=c("l","n"),stringsAsFactors=F)
df3<-data.frame("id"=c("r1","r2","r3"),"e1"=c(100,200,300),"e2"=c("x","y","z"),stringsAsFactors=F)
final.list <- vector(mode="list",length=nrow(df1))
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
     d1<-df1[i,]
     d2<-df2[df2$id==d1$id,]
     d3<-df3[df3$id==d1$id,]
     final.list[[i]]<-list(df1=d1,df2=d2,df3=d3)
}
final.list

[[1]]
[[1]]$df1
  id c1 c2
1 r1  1  a

[[1]]$df2
  id   d1 d2
1 r1 1000  l

[[1]]$df3
  id  e1 e2
1 r1 100  x


[[2]]
[[2]]$df1
  id c1 c2
2 r2  2  b

[[2]]$df2
[1] id d1 d2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]$df3
  id  e1 e2
2 r2 200  y


[[3]]
[[3]]$df1
  id c1 c2
3 r3  3  c

[[3]]$df2
  id   d1 d2
2 r3 3000  n

[[3]]$df3
  id  e1 e2
3 r3 300  z
```

I am restructuring the data this way to use the list of lists in parallelized code so as to avoid the exporting of all five dataframes worth of data to each of the cores. So, I am trying to improve efficiency on memory utilization.

Is there a faster way to restructure my data and combine it into a list of lists?

Comment: Can you post some sample data from the 5 dataframes and what you want the final output to look like?  'rbind' or 'join' might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Monk - added some data and final output to post.

Answer (score 0):

If your final list format doesn't have to match exactly with what you've shown, this code might work.

```
# Create dataframes  
df1 <- data.frame("id"=c("r1","r2","r3"), "c1"=c(1,2,3), "c2"=c("a","b","c"), stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame("id"=c("r1","r3"), "d1"=c(1000,3000), "d2"=c("l","n"), stringsAsFactors=F)
df3 <- data.frame("id"=c("r1","r2","r3"), "e1"=c(100,200,300),  "e2"=c("x","y","z"), stringsAsFactors=F)

# Rename columns (must be same for rbind)
colnames(df1) <- c('id', 'x1', 'x2'); colnames(df2) <- c('id', 'x1', 'x2'); colnames(df3) <- c('id', 'x1', 'x2')

# Rbind dataframes together
final.list <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

# Split into a list
final.list <- split(final.list, final.list$id)
final.list
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but my actual dataframes have different columns, and the one-to-many relationships that preclude the use of things like rbind. What I am wondering is whether the subsetting I do on a large set of dataframes (with say 10's of thousands of unique IDs) is the speed culprit. So, I am looking into `data.table` and it's `setKey` capabilities. I'm just going to have to test that.

Comment: Can you update the sample data you provided so that it is more reflective of your actual data (and what you want the final output to be)?